# how to disable input type = text on check box click if i have many inputs of the same name

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm getting many data and i'm looping into them in html so there are many inputs with the same name
My html code :

```
    {% for Permission in Permissions %}
    <tr>

    <td style="text-align:center;">  {{Permission.perm_label}} </td>
    <td style="text-align:center;"> <input type="checkbox" class="permUsersClass" id="permUsers"  name="permUsers" value="permUsers" {% if Permission.perm_users  != 0 %}  checked {% endif %}> <input type="text" id="permUsersText" name="Users" value="{{Permission.perm_users }}" > </td>
    <td style="text-align:center;"> <input type="checkbox" id="permProfile" name="permProfile" value="permProfile" {% if Permission.perm_profile  != 0 %}  checked {% endif %} > <input type="text" id="permProfileText" name="Profile"  value="{{Permission.perm_profile }}"></td>
    <td style="text-align:center;"> <input type="checkbox" id="permSchedule" name="permSchedule" value="permSchedule" {% if Permission.perm_schedule  != 0 %}  checked {% endif %}> <input type="text" id="permScheduleText" name="Schedule"  value="{{Permission.perm_schedule  }}"> </td>
    <td style="text-align:center;"> <input type="checkbox" id="permAccount" name="permAccount" value="permAccount" {% if Permission.perm_accounting  != 0 %} checked {% endif %}> <input type="text" name="Accounting" value="{{Permission.perm_accounting}}"> </td>

    </tr>
    {% endfor %}
```

My javascript functiom

```
      $('.permUsersClass').change(function () {


       $('input[name=Users')[0].disabled = !this.checked;
       }).change();
```

In javascript how to disable specific text box and not just the first one

Comment: How about `$("#boxID").prop('disabled', true);` ? You know why you have set ID in your html script

Comment: I can't see the same "name" also the IDs are not the same so... where's the problem exactly? Just use the IDs or loop over the elements gotten by class name.

Comment: FYI, you disable the first one because you have the `[0]`th element disabled. You need to loop over all fields and check for the ID of each element, disabling whichever you need